# arrow function inside functional component is undefined react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a like button counter with react hooks. I have defined the arrow function this way, but  I'm getting  IncreaseLikeHandler is undefined.

```
import {useState} from "react";
import './App.css';


function App() {

  IncreaseLikeHandler = () =>{
    setLikeCounter(likeCounter+1);
    };
    
  const [likeCounter, setLikeCounter] = useState(0);
  const [dislikeCounter, setDislikeCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>test</p>
      <button onClick={IncreaseLikeHandler}>like</button>
      <button>dislike</button>
      <div>{likeCounter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Comment: You're setting `IncreaseLikeHandler` equal to something before you've even declared it as a variable. In JS you have to declare variables before you assign them, using either `var/let/const` (google those to check the differences).

Answer (score 1):

You first have to declare it then you can use it

without declaration `eslint` will complain

> ```
> 'IncreaseLikeHandler' is not defined. (no-undef)eslint
> ```

```
const IncreaseLikeHandler = () => {
  setLikeCounter(likeCounter + 1);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside the fanction component you must use (const, let and var) to define the functions.